# Redirect old wordpress URLs articles to new website and new permalinks URLs structure

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am making a new website to replace an existing website. And we are not keeping the previous permalink structure : see below
OLD URL = http www .domain.com/article.php?ID=3242
NEW URL = http www .domain.com/author/post-name

So we want to redirect the old urls to the new ones. How could I do that easily in the htaccess file ?

I tried redirect 301 but does not work.
RedirectMatch 301 ^/article.php?ID=3242 http://www.domain.com/author/post-name

Comment: Does it work if you escape the `?` with a \ ? So `^/article.php\?ID=3242`

Comment: No I tried but does not work.

Comment: Ah sorry; just checked an old .htaccess file of mine, and realised why it won't work.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectMatch` won't match the query string (the part after the `?`).  [This article](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/) explains a bit more, but this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/article\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ID=3242$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/author/post-name [R=302,L]
```

Note that I changed it to a 302 redirect while you're testing; I'd only change it to a 301 once you're sure you've got it right (to avoid browsers caching incorrect redirects).

Comment: Ouah cool. But where should I put it : before/after the rules of wordpress ?   # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /withoutmodel/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /withoutmodel/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: I'd put it before the WordPress rules; straight after `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`.  That'll mean you have two `RewriteEngine On` directives - you could remove the second one.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `.htaccess` file (just edit your question)?

Comment: Works great now ! Thank you so much.  For info I put the lines before the modrewrite rules of WORDPRESS.  And for localhost dev where I got subdir for my projects I had to remove the ^ rule here : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /article\.php$

Comment: Just one detail more : is there a way to remove the querystring in the redirected url ? Because the querystring is stil here in the final page : ...domain.com/author/post-name/?ID=3242

Comment: Excellent; glad to help.  This question has an approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156301/htaccess-remove-query-string